# heroku MYSQL issues?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm un-able to de-bug the below error locally. When I create a new account in production I get the following error:

```
2014-05-30T18:37:08.908868+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/account_steps.organization_details" for 99.234.25.253 at 2014-05-30 18:37:08 +0000
2014-05-30T18:37:08.972705+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://limitless-tor-2926.herokuapp.com/account_steps/organization_details
2014-05-30T18:37:09.081125+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/account_steps/organization_details" for 99.234.25.253 at 2014-05-30 18:37:09 +0000
2014-05-30T18:37:09.096189+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"organization_details"}
2014-05-30T18:37:09.119222+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered account_steps/organization_details.html.erb within layouts/application (11.1ms)
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138721+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138726+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql::Error: : SELECT  `organizations`.* FROM `organizations`  WHERE `organizations`.`account_id` = ? LIMIT 1):
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138728+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:                 </ul>
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138730+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:               </div>
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138731+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:           <% end %>
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138733+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:         <%= f.fields_for :organization, @account.build_organization do |org| %>
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138735+00:00 app[web.1]:     23: 
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138736+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:         <div class="form-group">
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138738+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:           <div class="row">
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138740+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/account_steps/organization_details.html.erb:22:in `block in _app_views_account_steps_organization_details_html_erb__2844923124578816920_70159039034840'
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138742+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/account_steps/organization_details.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_account_steps_organization_details_html_erb__2844923124578816920_70159039034840'
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138743+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/account_steps_controller.rb:8:in `show'
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138745+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-30T18:37:09.138746+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-30T18:37:08.921225+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by AccountStepsController#index as 
2014-05-30T18:37:08.985227+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 52ms (ActiveRecord: 10.7ms)
2014-05-30T18:37:09.095524+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by AccountStepsController#show as HTML
2014-05-30T18:37:09.110362+00:00 app[web.1]: Mysql::Error: : SELECT  `organizations`.* FROM `organizations`  WHERE `organizations`.`account_id` = ? LIMIT 1
2014-05-30T18:37:09.135830+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 39ms
```

Note that I've added the ClearDB add-on to the application so I'm not sure why I'm getting these MYSQL errors. I don't get them in development so it is definitely a heroku issue and impossible for me to debug locally.

Please help clear this up for me as soon as possible!

Comment: Do you see anything else in the logs with specific MySQL errors? The log dump you pasted doesn't really give anyone enough info to help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

This log has all the hallmarks of not having the tables set up correctly in the production DB. With such an inconclusive error log, I can only recommend doing this from your local cmd:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

This will populate your db's in your `ClearDB` instance, allowing you to run the queries you need

--

If this does not work, you'll have to provide your models & view code for the views mentioned in the error log

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Heroku before, apparently I had to run `rake db:migrate` on the Heroku app server.  Try running `heroku run rake db:migrate` in your local application's directory where the heroku remote is set up.

Try opening another terminal and `--tail` the error logs to see it log as it goes.